# Can third-party ChatGPT plugins see requests we send to ChatGPT?

Tags: chatgpt, privacy

Can third-party bots, apps, or plugins that rely on ChatGPT see which code/questions we send/ask to ChatGPT?

Comment: Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange. Despite this question score being relatively high compared to other questions and that it became a Hot Network Question a few days ago, I'm afraid I can't recommend using it as a good example for new questions as it doesn't look to follow the guidelines set in this community [tour], [ask] and the guidance in the Ask Question page. If you have any questions about the referred documents, please post a question in [meta].

Comment: ok,no probleme. That was an interesting question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, They can see. Important thing is how they use they data is upto their privacy policy.

When you use the ChatGPT API, the text you input is transmitted to OpenAI's servers for the AI to generate a response. Access to this data is subject to OpenAI's data usage policy. Third-party plugins or applications that integrate with ChatGPT could have their own policies regarding data access and handling. It is important to thoroughly review the privacy policies and terms of service of any third-party software to ensure your data is treated with the level of privacy and security you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I know OpenAI can see what we send to chatpgpt. Inwas wondering if that was the same for plugins. Some of them do not say anything about data privacy. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I want to qualify the answer of @c.sankhala: Plugins can see all info that ChatGPT decides to pass to them.

This doesn't sound much different because you have no control what ChatGPT passes to plugins. But eg if you use 2 plugins with totally disparate areas of responsibility, you may have more confidence in which part of your question/data will be passed to which one.